# Applying different values to string row

Tags: string-manipulation, row

This must be easy but I'm stuck, I want to create this row:

> {< 1 >}{< 4 >}{< 4 >}{< 22 >}{< 3 >}{< 12 >}{< 54 >}{< 65 >}

from this list

```
t = {1, 4, 4, 22, 3, 12, 54, 65};
```

I tried many things like

```
d = "{<" t[[i]] ">}";
t = {1, 4, 4, 22, 3, 12, 54, 65};
Row[Table[d, {i, 1, 8}]]
```

but nothing works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
t = {1, 4, 4, 22, 3, 12, 54, 65}
```

Other ways:

```
StringRiffle[t, {"{<", ">}{<", ">}"}]


StringJoin[StringTemplate@"{<``>}" /@ t]
```

And similar but not the same:

```
Row[List /@ Skeleton /@ t]
```

[image]

Comment: The second one is a very good approach because I can manipulate/change the pattern easily

Comment: @Kuba thanks for introducing me to `StringRiffle`...guess I should have known about it...:)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
t = {1, 4, 4, 22, 3, 12, 54, 65};
a = ">}{<"
Row[{"{<"}~Join~Riffle[t, a]~Join~{">}"}]
```

or

```
l = "{<";
r = ">}";
Row[{l, ##, r} & @@ Riffle[t, Row[{r, l}]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

In:

```
(*Method 1*)
xs = {1, 4, 4, 22, 3, 12, 54, 65};
box = Function[x, "{<" ~~ ToString[x] ~~ ">}", Listable];
StringJoin@box@xs


(*Method 2*)
rules =  {"{" -> "{<", ", " -> ">}{<", "}" -> ">}"}
xs // ToString // StringReplace[#, rules] &

(*Method 3*)
textString = TextString[{#}, ListFormat -> {"{<", "", ">}"}] &;
xs // Map[textString] // StringJoin
```

Out:

```
{<1>}{<4>}{<4>}{<22>}{<3>}{<12>}{<54>}{<65>}
{<1>}{<4>}{<4>}{<22>}{<3>}{<12>}{<54>}{<65>}
{<1>}{<4>}{<4>}{<22>}{<3>}{<12>}{<54>}{<65>}
```